# Splitting javascript into several files

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code which is basically

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Global variable definitions
    // Bunch of functions depending on variables
});
```

Is there any way for me to split these functions up into several files even though they are all mostly dependent on each other?

I'm creating a html5 game and I want to separate a lot of the code, for example I'd like code for drawing objects to be in a specific file, code for updating the game state in another file and so on so I can still access all the global variables.

Is there a way to do this without a lot of hassle or rewriting all the code?

Comment: Why the jquery tag? Although there is some jquery code, the question is not related to jquery at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of people struggled with this just as you are doing right now.

The old way to do that was to have a namespace object, like `MYAPP`. This way, the only global variable was `MYAPP`, and you put all your functions/variables on it, like this:

file1.js

```
(function() {
    var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};

    MYAPP.func = function() { console.log(1); };
}());
```

file2.js

```
(function() {
    var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};

    MYAPP.func(); // 1
}());
```

The main issue with browser-side javascript is that it doesn't have "include", or "require", as other server-side languages have. This made it hard to "include" a JS file (and thus its functions/variables) where you wanted it.

Nowadays, people have thought about it and solved the problem mainly in 2 ways:

- The AMD way: Asynchronous Module Definition, allows you to asynchronously load other JS files, thus having some kind of browser-side "include". The best example of this kind of library is [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). The asynchronous loading is good for development purposes, but the production-code has to be pre-compiled for performance matters.
- The CommonJS way: using the node.js way, you synchronously require a module, and a module is defined using the `module.exports` object. However, it requires a compilation part before you use the code on the browser. The best example of this kind of library is [browserify](http://browserify.org/). Note that the compilation part can be almost seamless with a watcher.

Comment: I've heard a lot of good things about AMD recently. Do you have any preferred reading on the subject?

Comment: @ChristopherW Honestly, my preference goes for browserify. But the documentation on requirejs.org is really good if you want to get started.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to access those global variables from everywhere,there are still many ways to modularize your code. Here's one :

```
// file 1
(function(){
    myapp = myapp || {};
    myapp.myvar = ...;
    myapp.myfunc = function(){...};
})();

// file 2
(function(){
    myapp = myapp || {};
    myaapp.myothervar = ...
    myapp.myotherfunc = function(){...};
    myapp.start = function(){...};
    }
})();

// last file

$(myapp.start);
```

But you clearly will have to refactor your code a little.

A variant is to define submodules, so that "global variables" are less global. It's generally more manageable if you don't expose too much : if you have 20 files and any LOC of any file can access any variable defined elsewhere, it will be a little hard to know what happens.

Comment: @Denys, your code is missing closing parentheses at the end of file 1 & file 2.

Comment: @Codemonkey Right. Fixed (don't hesitate to do it yourself next time ;) )

Comment: Didn't even occur to me, I'm not that well-versed in SO!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at namespacing:

http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/

Namespacing is a concept of the [module pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_pattern).

By using a layered approach to code structure, you move from abstract to more concrete objects to structure your code. Usually you would start off with an overarching object.

```
var JSApp = JSApp || {};
JSApp.someMethod = function() {};
JSApp.someProperty = "foo";
JSApp.someObject = {
    internalStuff: "bar"
};
JSApp.implement = function() {
    this.someMethod();
};
```

In a different file:

```
JSApp.someFactory = function() {
    //JSApp is the common namespace.
};
```

Establishing an overarching structure like so allows for a single global. Now you can break up your code into multiple modules (different) files by adding your code to the `JSApp` object.

All you need to do to implement is to call whatever you need within your `$(document).ready()` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    JSApp.implement();
});
```

Granted, there are checks that should be implemented before you go around all willy-nilly assigning objects to a namespace, even if you THINK it's supposed to be there.